# how to dispatch action in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've created a list of users using action getUsers() and now I wanna delete any user.
so I've created an action:

```
export function deleteUser(id) {
  return {
    type: DELETE_USER,
    payload: id
  };
}
```

set up reducer:

```
case DELETE_USER :
        return {
          ...state, 
          users: state.users.filter(i => i.id !== action.id)
        }
```

initialState is this:

```
const initialState = {
    users: [
      {
        id: 1, 
        name: 'Oksana'
      },
      {
        id: 2, 
        name: 'Serge'
      },

    ],
    loading: true
}
```

and now time to dispatch deleteUser()

this is my Users component:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ users: state.users });
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    deleteUser: id => {
      dispatch(deleteUser(id))
    }
  }
     
};


const Users = (props) => {
  const { users } = props.users;
  console.log(props);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Users</h2>
      {users.map((user) => {
        return (
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-1">
            <li>{user.name}</li>
            <button onClick={() => props.deleteUser(user.id)}>x</button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Users);
```

I tried to rewrite mapDispatchToProps but it does not work. I click delete (x) button and it behaves dumb. no errors on terminal.

Comment: You should write `action.payload` i.e. `users: state.users.filter(i => i.id !== action.payload)`

Comment: correct ! thanks !:)